# How can I display the output of an array list in a popup window using Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Below is what I want to display:

```
JTextArea result = new JTextArea(10,20);
ArrayList<String> result_set = gen.getResult();
for(Iterator it = result_set.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    String data = (String)it.next();
    result.append(data+"\n");
}
```

How can I put a `JTextArea` in a popup window?

Answer (score 3):

First you would add the JTextArea to a JScrollPane.

You can then add the scrollpane to a JPopupMenu.

Or you can add the scrollpane to a JOptionPane.

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information. There are sections on "How to Use Menus" and "How to Make Dialogs".